# how to change canvas fabric to static canvas

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js to build an app in html5.
I want to remove mouse event listener of fabric canvas to make it like static canvas but I don't know how.
Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
(function() {
  var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');

  canvas.add(
    new fabric.Rect({ top: 100, left: 100, width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#f55' }),
    new fabric.Circle({ top: 140, left: 230, radius: 75, fill: 'green' }),
    new fabric.Triangle({ top: 300, left: 210, width: 100, height: 100, fill: 'blue' })
  );

  fabric.Image.fromURL('../lib/pug.jpg', function(img) {
    canvas.add(img.set({ left: 400, top: 350, angle: 30 }).scale(0.25));
  });

  function animate() {
    canvas.item(0).animate('top', canvas.item(0).getTop() === 500 ? '100' : '500', { 
      duration: 1000,
      onChange: canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas),
      onComplete: animate
    });
  }
  animate();
})();
```

Source: http://fabricjs.com/static_canvas/

Hope this help.

Comment: Check these demos for unselectable objects, locked objects, etc. : http://fabricjs.com/customization/

Comment: Thanks for your help, but in this I just want to toggle remove mouse listener on fabric. In detail, I just want to toggle remove event mousedown and mousemove to range select.

Comment: By the way, I have my solution by using this.

"fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'mousedown', this.onMouseDown);
        fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'mousemove', this.onMouseMove);"

Comment: You have a simple solution: canvas.selection = false;

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue. The way I solved it was by passing in the option "selectable: false" to new fabric objects.

```
    this.backgroundFabric = new fabric.Rect({ fill: "black",
            width: dimX,
            height: dimY ,
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            selectable: false });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have my solution here:  
    `fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'mousedown', this.onMouseDown);      
fabric.util.removeListener(fabric.document, 'mousemove', this.onMouseMove);`